# Python pandas: how to change categorical values in between 2 different categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, trading

Hi everyone I am working on stock market data and I was wondering how to change the pandas data frame as below

| From: Signal | To: Signal_new |
| --- | --- |
| Buy | Buy |
| Buy | Hold |
| Buy | Hold |
| Sell | Sell |
| Sell | Hold |
| Sell | Hold |
| Sell | Hold |
| Buy | Buy |

thanks in advance!

Comment: Will you please show more of your dataframe? We can't help you because we don't what rows to change and why.

Comment: Or are you just trying to change every value of the same type after the first to `Hold`?

Comment: I'm going to read between the lines here, and assume you are saying "if the signal is the same as the previous row, change it to 'Hold'".  Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[df['Signal'] == df['Signal'].shift(1)] = 'Hold'
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Signal
0    Buy
1   Hold
2   Hold
3   Sell
4   Hold
5   Hold
6   Hold
7    Buy
```